# does python support incremental recomputation?

Tags: python

```
class foo:
   def __init__(self, val=6):
     self.val = val
   def a(self):
     self.val +=5
   def b(self):
      self.val +=10
   def c(self):
      self.val *=10
   def make(self):
     self.a()
     self.b()
     self.c()

obj= foo()
obj.make()
```

Take an example of the code above, at times i want to take note of the value of self.val as it enters a method and as it exists from a method. Secondily, assuming results of b() take 1 hr to compute, after a while i notice there was an error in c(), that needs modification, is it possible to begin execution just after b() has finished with execution, without running the whole program again? does python have support incremental recomputation?

Answer (score 3):

The code is wrong, but regardless — just save the result when you exit the function. There is nothing here that should be done on a language level.

Comment: To go a step further, if you need to store the results in such a way that you can adjust the code and then try running it again on partial output, then the pickle module is your friend; it can serialize and deserialize Python data, allowing you to store your temporary data between runs. Just serialize the temporary result and some kind of marker indicating what the next step of execution is, and you're in business.

Comment: ok, Seems pickle is soln of choice. my next problem is, how to enable this during experimental runs only. Possible to define a switch to turn off/on this functionality of serializaing/deserializing objects.

Comment: Use `if experimental:` statements and get the value of experimental from the command line or a config file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your goal is to save the object in case of system failure so the answer would be to pickle obj and store somewhere.